# How far finiteness dimension can be from edges? Example for $f_m(S/I)\ge depth S/I+2$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, local-cohomology, krull-dimension

Let $ (R,m) $ be a commutative unital noetherian local ring (with $m$ as its maximal ideal), $ I $ an ideal of $ R $, and $ M $ a finite $R$-module with $\dim M\gt 0$. $f_I(M) = \inf\ \{i  : H_I^i(M)\ \text{is not finitely generated}\}$ is defined in chapter 9 of *Brodmann-Sharp*'s  *Local Cohomology* book.
I know that $$\operatorname{depth} M\le f_m(M)\le \dim M$$ 
the question is that how far $f_m(M)$ can be from edges? I specially interested in the case that $M$ is $S/I$ where $S$ is polynomial ring (which one can use software). So is there an example that $\dim S/I\gt \operatorname{depth} S/I+2$ and:

> 1) $$f_m(S/I)\gt \operatorname{depth} S/I+1$$

and that

> 2)$$f_m(S/I)\lt \dim S/I+1$$